# Voltage in a circuit at a particular point

Tags: resistance, homework, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Can anyone help me in understanding how to simplify this circuit and get the voltage at point V? The negative terminal and 1 ohm resistor have a ground in between.

Comment: You need to show some effort. What circuit analysis techniques are you familiar with?

Comment: Maybe start by redrawing it with the ground at the bottom. The numbers are chosen so that you can do any calculations in your head.

Comment: I am familiar with KVL, KCL. Although I think there's a simpler approach here. The only thing thats confusing me is the point V. I can't figure out how to simplify the circuit with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll redraw it to see if that helps you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKoZ5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are only two unknown node voltages: \$V_x\$ and \$V_y\$. I think you are saying that you want to find \$V_x\$.

You should be able to work out that \$I_1=I_2+I_3\$, for example. And also that while \$V_y=I_1\cdot R_1\$ (because that's how to compute the voltage drop across a resistor when you know the current through it), you should also be able to work out that \$V_y=6\:\text{V}-I_2\cdot R_2=6\:\text{V}-I_3\cdot\left( R_3+R_4\right)\cdot\$.

If you are savvy enough, you might notice that \$R_2\$ appears to be *in parallel* with \$R_3+R_4\$ and use that fact to help simplify the schematic a bit and work out the value of \$I_1\$ from that.